# Windows laptop will not turn on after installing Wireshark

Tags: windows-10, laptop, wireshark, dell-xps, winpcap

I have a Dell XPS laptop running Windows 10. I installed Wireshark from [here](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html), including Npcap from the same installer. All the additional options were left default.

After closing the laptop lid for a while and returning about 2hrs later, the computer no longer turns on. The screen remains completely black when using touch, keys, and the power button. The power button does not light up when clicked, however the keyboard backlight does turn on. I have experienced no issues with this laptop prior.

FWIW, the keyboard backlight turns off around 3s after clicking the power button, the fan as well.

Comment: In my view, your Laptop may have experienced a Hardware failure, which just coincided with time after installing Wireshark. If Laptop battery is removable, see if you can long press power button for 30-40 seconds (after battery removal)  to remove any static charge and retry.

Comment: My initial thought was that the Npcap drivers were causing issues, but this is definitely a possibility too. I will try draining the static charge when I next get the chance. Thanks!

Comment: Wireshark and Npcap (used the latter) do not cause this issue.

Comment: @DayTrip - I have never in 30 years ever experienced a hardware problem caused by software, if you said your machine wasn’t booting, that might be software but it won’t even turn on. Thats hardware

Comment: If you can't even enter BIOS/UEFI, it's almost certainly *not* due to any software installed! Seems more like a dead battery.

Comment: If the boot of the operating system starts, but fails because of a wrong driver, you should be able to start windows in safe mode. If not, then as others already stated, it isn't caused by the WireShark driver.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry the confusion!

It just turned out to be a coincidence that the battery failed just as I installed Wireshark. For future readers, the comments are absolutely correct. A Windows driver cannot be the cause of a hardware/BIOS failure, and Windows safe mode can be used in a situation where a malfunctioning driver is preventing the OS from starting.

For anyone in a similar situation, do what @patkim said and drain residual power from the system and perform the standard procedure recommended by your computer’s manufacturer.